# Вызов коструктора предка без его определения у наследника

Tags: наследование, c++, классы, конструктор

В общем есть класс A, который имеет несколько конструкторов.

Есть класс B, который переопределяет один из них.

Я хочу создать класс B, но использовать при это один из не переопределенных конструкторов класса A.

Обязательно ли надо будет писать у класса конструктор заглушку, который тупо будет вызывать конструктор класса A и более ничего?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

В C++11 можно наследовать конструкторы:

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

class A {
public:
    A( int ) { cout << "A int " << endl;}
    A( const char* a ) { cout << "A: " << a << endl;}
};

class B : public A {
public:
    using A::A; // НАСЛЕДУЕМ КОНСТРУКТОР
    B( const char* a ) : A( a ) { cout << "B: " << a << endl; }
};

int main() {
    B b1( "hello" );
    B b2( 2 );
    return 0;
}
```

Ссылка в [ideone.com](http://ideone.com/s2zQD6)

Статья в [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/C%2B%2B11#Object_construction_improvement)

Стандарт C++11. Раздел 12.9

[Перевод блога Бьярна Страуструпа. Раздел про наследование конструкторов](http://sergeyteplyakov.blogspot.ru/2012/05/c-11-faq.html#inheriting)

Comment: Шикарно!

То что надо.

Comment: Все отлично заработало!

Меня только смущает, что using дофига для чего используется уже...